# in joomla, how do I create a menu with links to the last 5 added articles in a category?

Tags: joomla

I'd like to create a menu with links to the last added articles in a certain category. So every time a new article is added to the category the menu is updated with a link to it (and possibly the oldest is removed).

I know it seems quite simple, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Thanks in advance,
Saul

Comment: will a single link be OK or you need multiple links for latest items?

Comment: I found the answer by the way ... Answer my above question and I will post the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not do this with the Latest News module? You can control how many articles are shown and just output then as a list of links.

Comment: indeed, it was exactly what I wanted. For some reason I thought this Latest News module was intended to use with rss. Really thanks!

Comment: Doh! Why did'nt I think of that? Nice one Jeepstone :)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done directly in joomla - so you may want to look into using an extension similar to [artcats](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-listing/5204) and then set it up for your requirements.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll take a look at this module, but the Latest News module indicated by Jeepstone worked like a charm. Thanks anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible through Joomla's Menu Manager. The menu cannot change dynamically natively.

However, I imagine you don't really need it to be a menu, but rather simply an unordered list. That is rather than a main menu with "Home | About | Latest News" and the 5 most recent article titles in drop down under Latest News, it would make far more sense to have a module on your homepage or interior that whether bullet points or styled another way through CSS would just the title of the 5 latest articles.

For that login to the control panel, extensions > module manager > new > latest news, and set the count, category id, position, enable it, and such. To note, the native Latest News module is extremely limited.  If you just want titles it is fine, but if you wish to have teaser text, dates, and every other option under the sun you could use Gavick News Show or Gavick News Show Pro. Both are free modules from tools.gavick.com.

Hope this helps.

Christopher

Answer (score 0):

With the new 1.6 release of Joomla! (Jan 10th), they've added a new module type called 'Articles Category' that lists a configurable number of articles from a category in a configurable order.
I havn't played around with 1.6 too much but that seems like it would do the trick!